# Increase performance of Windows apps

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, performance, winapi

I have imported an app from Visual Studio compiler to MinGW and I faced a problem – performance degradation. Usage of CPU increased from 30% to 100%.
There is one interesting thing. If before running my app or during, I’ve run Windows Media Player – performance of my app is going to fine. CPU usage is going down till 30% and works faster (about 10 times faster).
I’ve googled it and found. It relates to a service, which names as a Multimedia Class Scheduler Service (MMCSS). The main problem is: this service forks under Windows Vista and later, but I’ve tested and imported my app under Win XP.
So, does anyone know how to use this feature under XP? And how Windows Media Player increases performance of my app?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Media Player changes the resolution of the system multimedia timer. Basically, this occurs when your application really should be using something like the High Performance Timer but is using the multimedia timer instead, which simply doesn't have and isn't intended to have the necessary accuracy or resolution to be a high-performance timer. As a result, any timings in your program essentially don't work as they should, which is especially bad if you're trying to sleep or block for a fixed time.

Comment: Looks like it didn't help. I've deleted all Sleep()s, and set Priority of Process (HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS or REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS) and all my threads (THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST or THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL) to appropriate vals. After that performance increased only a little.

Comment: @Gabriel.vs: That is not even close to a solution. Also note that deleting sleeps will drive _up_ your CPU% (a sleeping thread cosnumes 0% CPU.

Comment: That is a terrible thing to do. Please abstain from playing with priorities unless you understand _exactly_ what they do (they do NOT make your program faster). As DeadMG pointed out, chances are good that either your performance is tied to the scheduler granularity or your measurements depend on the multimedia timer resolution and are therefore wrong. A third unlikely possibility would be speed step. In no case will playing with priorities change anything.

Comment: After all, I've introduced implementation of my own "Sleeping" action (by using "High Performance Timer" , thx for it @DeadMG). So, now response of all my threads (and appropriate actions inside of them) works faster. But, one problem still is present - too high load of CPU!! 100%!!! Due to this CPU load, my app works not ehought fast. Any other ideas?